# In R, how to first use a loop to create matrices and then stack them?

Tags: r, list, loops, stack

Taking into account your past answers, I've changed for the following:

```
n <- 100
B <- 20
S <- 50
alpha <- 0.3
beta <- 1.2
theta <- alpha*beta

for (i in 1:S) {
  ###
  sim_original_samples <- rgamma(n, alpha, beta)                      # for each S, we have a sample of 100 observations
  sim_original_samples_X_bar <- mean(sim_original_samples)            # for each dataset, compute the sample mean and input it 
  sim_bs_samples_X_bar <- matrix(0,B,1)
  # in the same loop we are going to compute the sample mean per bootstrap per original sample i
  ####
  ####
  for (j in 1:B) {
    sim_bs_samples <- sample(sim_original_samples,n,replace=TRUE)
    # for each original sample, we are going to draw B times a bootstrap sample
    sim_bs_samples_X_bar[j] <- mean(sim_bs_samples)
    # all the elements of this matrix should be the bootstrap sample mean
    var_sim_bs_samples <- matrix(0,B,1)
    var_sim_bs_samples[j] <- (sim_bs_samples_X_bar[j] - sim_original_samples_X_bar)^2
    se_sim_bs_samples <- sqrt((1/B*sum(var_sim_bs_samples)))
  }
  ####
  ####
  # now we want to compute the asymptotic CI of i)
  z <- 1.96                              
  var_gamma <- alpha*beta^2/n      
  CI_sim_asy_norm <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = S)         # create a vector for the CI
  names <- c("Lower bound", "Upper bound", "teta covered")
  colnames(CI_sim_asy_norm) <- names
  #
  CI_sim_asy_norm[i,1] <- theta - z*sqrt(var_gamma)
  CI_sim_asy_norm[i,2] <- theta + z*sqrt(var_gamma)
  CI_sim_asy_norm[i,3] <- theta >= CI_sim_asy_norm[i,1] & theta <= CI_sim_asy_norm[i,2]
  # check whether the true parameter of interest is covered 
  ####
  ####
  # do the same for the asymptotic BS CI of ii)
  CI_sim_asy_bs <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = S)
  colnames(CI_sim_asy_bs) <- names
  CI_sim_asy_bs[i,1] <- sim_original_samples_X_bar - z*se_sim_bs_samples
  CI_sim_asy_bs[i,2] <- sim_original_samples_X_bar + z*se_sim_bs_samples
  CI_sim_asy_bs[i,3] <- theta >= CI_sim_asy_bs[i,1] & theta <= CI_sim_asy_bs[i,2]
  ####
  ####
  # do the same for the percentile BS CI of iii) assuming B = 1000 for simplicity
  sim_bs_samples_X_bar_sorted <- sort(sim_bs_samples_X_bar, decreasing=FALSE)
  CI_sim_percentile <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = S)
  colnames(CI_sim_percentile) <- names
  CI_sim_percentile[i,1] <-  sim_bs_samples_X_bar_sorted[1000*(0.05/2)]
  CI_sim_percentile[i,2] <-  sim_bs_samples_X_bar_sorted[1000*((1-0.05)/2)]
  CI_sim_percentile[i,3] <-  theta >= CI_sim_percentile[i,1] & theta <= CI_sim_percentile[i,2]
  ####
}
```

The issue I have now, is that only the last row of the CI is filled (when filled) whereas it should be filled for all rows.
Where is the issue ? I cannot see it.

That is, for each original sample i, I draw B bootstrap samples.
For each, original sample i, I want to construct confidence intervals.
For each confidence intervals I want to know whether the true parameter (theta) has been contained in each of the CI.

Hence, I'd have 50 confidence intervals.
For the bootstrap one it is based on the estimates of the 20 simulations (per original sample).

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

## The Question

Let's divide your question into a two parts:

1. How to create the data: samples, re-samples, means, etc.
2. How to create a multi-dimensional object

## 1. Creating the data

### Configuration from your question

```
S     <-   5
n     <- 100
B     <-   2
alpha <-   0.3
beta  <-   1.2
```

### Sample and re-sample

```
require( tidyverse )
U    <- map_dfc( 1:S, ~rgamma( n, alpha, beta ))
Ubar <- map_dfc( 1:S, mean )
V    <- map_dfc( 1:S, ~sample( U[[ . ]], n, replace = TRUE ))
Vbar <- map_dfc( 1:S, mean )
```

### What shape are these?

```
dim( U )
#  100   5

dim( V )
#  100   5

dim( Ubar )
#    1   5

dim( Vbar )
#    1   5
```

### Now, what did you want to stack? (and why?)

## 2. How to create a multi-dimensional object

Sometimes it can be helpful to pack data into a multi-dimensional object, in order to facilitate slicing along axes, or to select specific elements.

### Define the object

```
multi_dimensional <- array(
    data = 0:( S * B * n )
  , dim  = c( S, B, n )
  , dimnames = list(             # <---- names are optional
        paste0( 'X', 1:S )
      , paste0( 'Y', 1:B )
      , paste0( 'Z', 1:n )
    )
)

dim( multi_dimensional )
# [1]   5   2 100
```

### Slice, dice, and chop

```
multi_dimensional[ 1, 1, 1 ]
# [1] 0

multi_dimensional[ S, B, n ]
# [1] 999

multi_dimensional[ 1, 2, 1:10]
# Z1  Z2  Z3  Z4  Z5  Z6  Z7  Z8  Z9 Z10 
#  5  15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85  95 

multi_dimensional[ , , 1:2 ]
# , , Z1
# 
#    Y1 Y2
# X1  0  5
# X2  1  6
# X3  2  7
# X4  3  8
# X5  4  9
# 
# , , Z2
# 
#    Y1 Y2
# X1 10 15
# X2 11 16
# X3 12 17
# X4 13 18
# X5 14 19


multi_dimensional[ S, B, 99:100 ]
# Z99 Z100 
# 989  999
```

### Use the named dimensions, if you wish

```
multi_dimensional[ , , c( 'Z1', 'Z2' ) ]
# , , Z1
# 
#    Y1 Y2
# X1  0  5
# X2  1  6
# X3  2  7
# X4  3  8
# X5  4  9
# 
# , , Z2
# 
#    Y1 Y2
# X1 10 15
# X2 11 16
# X3 12 17
# X4 13 18
# X5 14 19

multi_dimensional[ c( 'X1', 'X3', 'X5' ), 'Y2' , c( 'Z1', 'Z2' ) ]
#    Z1 Z2
# X1  5 15
# X3  7 17
# X5  9 19
```

### Assign new values to specific elements

```
multi_dimensional[ 5, 1, 29:30 ] <-  c( 124.76, -5.0002 )
```

### Now show the new values

```
multi_dimensional[ 5, 1, 29:30 ]
#  Z29   Z30 
# 124.8  -5.0 

multi_dimensional[ 1:3, , 91:100 ]  # slice off a particular 3 x 10 block
# (not shown, due to size)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Initial Answer

I think you misunderstoond the purpose of matrix datatype as **in R matrices can't store complex objects such as other matrices**, they are limited to: double/numeric, integer, logical, character, complex and raw.

**Since you know the sizes of most of those data structures you should declare them beforehand AND outside the loops**.

What you seem to want is to be able to store a **list** of B matrices of arbitrary size (1 by n) that are generated on the second loop. You can declare an empty list and start adding the matrices in the second loop to it with something like this:

```
#You should declare this outside the loops.
matrix_j <- vector(mode='list', length=B)
#Then on the inner loop you can use [[]] to add elements to a list
for (j in 1:B) {
      matrix_j[[j]] <- sample(sim_original_samples[i],n,replace=TRUE)
```

or if you want an empty list of size 0, you can do `matrix_j <- list()` instead.

Next i didn't get if you want to compute the mean of each sample inside the list or if you want to compute the mean of the whole set of numbers, so:

1. First one would require you to you use the list apply function `lapply`,like this: `lapply(matrix_j,mean)`, which would return a list in which each element is the mean of the the element in the same position of `matrix_j`.
2. For the second possibility, i think it would be more appropriate to combine  the list elements into one simpler data structure and then compute the mean.

For your last problem, it seems to me that using `lists` (lists of lists) would solve your issue.
I'd create a big empty list and then add other lists as elements, as lists are allowed to contain other lists.

### Answer to edits:

**You are redeclaring lots of matrices inside loops**. This is a bad practice as every time you do this, you're assigning the initial values to them, so don't do that if you want to keep data from previous iterations.

Consider this part of your code:

```
for (j in 1:B) {
    sim_bs_samples <- sample(sim_original_samples,n,replace=TRUE)
    # for each original sample, we are going to draw B times a bootstrap sample
    sim_bs_samples_X_bar[j] <- mean(sim_bs_samples)
    # all the elements of this matrix should be the bootstrap sample mean
    var_sim_bs_samples <- matrix(0,B,1)
    var_sim_bs_samples[j] <- (sim_bs_samples_X_bar[j] - sim_original_samples_X_bar)^2
    se_sim_bs_samples <- sqrt((1/B*sum(var_sim_bs_samples)))
  }
```

Every time the `var_sim_bs_samples <- matrix(0,B,1)` line runs inside the loop, it substitutes the current matrix for a new matrix full of zeros and then the following line assigns something to its i-th line.

This declaration shouldn't happen inside the loop to avoid this behavior, hence why I told you to create a list and store each new matrix inside it OR move the declaration outside the loop and keep adding things to each line. So, to fix that, you could move the declaration to outside the loop like i've done here:

```
var_sim_bs_samples <- matrix(0,B,1)
    for (j in 1:B) {
            sim_bs_samples <- sample(sim_original_samples,n,replace=TRUE)
            # for each original sample, we are going to draw B times a bootstrap sample
            sim_bs_samples_X_bar[j] <- mean(sim_bs_samples)
            # all the elements of this matrix should be the bootstrap sample mean
            var_sim_bs_samples[j] <- (sim_bs_samples_X_bar[j] - sim_original_samples_X_bar)^2
            se_sim_bs_samples <- sqrt((1/B*sum(var_sim_bs_samples)))
          }
```

The reason only the last line of multiple matrices is present is because you're redeclaring (i.e. erasing it) as an empty matrix everytime with `<- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = S)`, so you're kinda emptying the matrix and then adding/assigning something to the i-th position, the last one happens to do it to the last position since i goes from 1 to `S`.

### Second Edit:

Just move the declarations outside of the loops where you're using them, like this:

```
n <- 100
B <- 20
S <- 50
alpha <- 0.3
beta <- 1.2
theta <- alpha*beta

CI_sim_asy_norm <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = S)
CI_sim_asy_bs <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = S)
CI_sim_percentile <- matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = S)

for (i in 1:S) {
  sim_original_samples <- rgamma(n, alpha, beta)                      
  sim_original_samples_X_bar <- mean(sim_original_samples)            
  sim_bs_samples_X_bar <- matrix(0,B,1)
  var_sim_bs_samples <- matrix(0,B,1)
  for (j in 1:B) {
    sim_bs_samples <- sample(sim_original_samples,n,replace=TRUE)
```

Your `CI_sim_percentile` will still be full of NAs, because this command `sim_bs_samples_X_bar_sorted[1000*(0.05/2)]` is just trying to access an index of `sim_bs_samples_X_bar_sorted` where there is no data and R assumes NA for that.

Comment: @dreamR check the Answer to your edits above, there was a good reason I said "You can declare this outside the loops" be it for lists or matrices, declaring them inside the loops will keep erasing whatever you put in them in the previous iteration of said loop.

Comment: Thank you but I must say that I have a hard time understanding how should I modify the edited code then. Any suggestion ? I understood your point but I don't know how to translate it into a new code.

Comment: @dreamR It happens in multiple parts of your code, I'll edit my answer to explain it a bit better while I try to untangle your code.